# Run tmux on ssh login

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, login, tmux

I want tmux to start on ssh login.

The typical advice is to add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ] && [[ $- =~ i ]]; then
  tmux attach-session -t mysession 2>/dev/null || tmux new-session -s mysession
fi
```

But when I log in, I get this error from tmux:

> lost server

...And then I'm in bash as usual.

---

UPDATE

When I add a sleep:

```bsh
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ] && [[ $- =~ i ]]; then
  tmux attach-session -t mysession 2>/dev/null || $(sleep 1 && tmux new-session -s mysession)
fi
```

...then it works. Strange! What is the reason?

Comment: What options do you pass to `ssh` when logging in? You must allocate a tty with `-t`. Also, you must avoid starting `tmux` if you're already in a `tmux` session (note that running `tmux` starts a new shell, which parses `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: I don't pass any options. I'm not in a tmux session, the above is run upon login via ssh.

Comment: You are changing the code in the question an awful lot. The original question did not have any `if`-statements at all.  The command substitution in your update does not make sense and would execute the output of `tmux new-session` whenever that session terminated.   There is otherwise no difference between the two codes.  Also, consider using `exec` as when one of your `tmux` sessions exits, it would give you an interactive `bash` shell (on the remote host) without `exec`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry. I only wrapped it in the `if` check to give context, I left it out initially to keep it simple. I didn't realise it was having an effect, as the error was the same regardless. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start `tmux` automatically in `~/.bash_profile` (for login shells), or `~/.bashrc` (for interactive shells), use something like

```bash
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]; then
    session=mysession

    if tmux has-session -t "$session" 2>/dev/null; then
        exec tmux attach-session -t "$session"
    else
        exec tmux new-session -s "$session"
    fi
fi
```

This would replace the shell with a `tmux` session if the shell is started by `ssh`, unless the current shell is already running inside `tmux`.

With newer versions of `tmux`, you should instead be able to use

```bash
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ -n $SSH_TTY ]]; then
    exec tmux new-session -A -s mysession
fi
```

You would want to do this *after* setting variables like `TERM` and `LC_*` (if you set these) that affect the terminal capabilities and locale.

Remember that `ssh` needs a pseudo-tty to run `tmux`, so you must connect with `ssh -t` (or use `RequestTTY force` in `~/.ssh/config` for the connection).

Comment: I tried your new approach and it works reliably! Thanks. I added the `&& [[ $- =~ i ]]` check so it works for ansible. One question though, why is it when I exit tmux it also closes the ssh session?

Comment: @lonix If you remove `exec` from my code, the original shell session that starts `tmux` would finish initializing, giving you a `bash` shell.  With `exec`, the login shell is replaced by `tmux`, which means that the SSH session would exit when `tmux` terminates.

Comment: Aaah that makes sense now. Your way is very elegant, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, one last question, really - when I add your code to `.bash_profile` it works, but it removes all terminal coloring (e.g. when using 'ls`, etc.) But when I add it to `.bashrc` the colors are shown as expected. I'm using ubuntu 19.10. Is this a weird config problem that is my fault, or is there a reason for it?

Comment: @lonix Put it towards the _end_ of the file, after any terminal initializations or other things you may do there.  You could obviously have it in `.bashrc` instead. In fact, I don't think it matters as I just remembered that `tmux` spawns logins shells by default (so it would try to run `~/.bash_profile` regardless, which makes my note about that wrong, so I will change it).

Comment: Thanks again, I moved it to `.bashrc` and now it's perfect!

Comment: `.bashrc` will also be sourced by **non-interactive** shells, when bash guesses (via some unreliable heuristics) that it was started by ssh. `SSH_TTY` will also be set when using `ssh -t some_command`, not only when an interactive shell was started. Executing another program from `.bashrc` has the potential of breaking things in other perverse ways (e.g. because bash is sourcing its start-up files with the job control turned off).

Comment: @user414777 Thanks! I forgot that `bash` uses heuristics under some circumstances.